# PHP mysqli Calculating total of array results

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have searched for the last 3 days, but I can't find a solution. I am trying to calculate the total points of the lowest 5 points for a player in an array, I have tried array_sum but I can't get it to work, no matter what I try it just displays the 5 lowest values of the array, but doesn't add them together, here is the code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['calc'])) {

    $player = $_SESSION['id'];

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE player_id='$player' ORDER by points ASC");

    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($row_count>=10) { // checks that at least 10 rows available
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT points FROM scores WHERE player_id='$player' ORDER by points ASC LIMIT 5"); // select 5 lowest points
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $total = array($row['points']);
                $sum = array_sum($total);
                echo $sum;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and get give feedback shortly. Your assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new array in each iteration in your loop. Either add elements to an array in the loop and then use array_sum once the loop has finished or simply add the values to the sum.

E.g.

```
$sum = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $sum += $row['points'];
}
echo $sum;
```

You could also simply use the SUM() function in your SQL query. That's probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a summation in the query to save yourself processing time and have less to transfer between the DB and your application.

Basically this should do what you want.  I haven't tested it personally but it should work the same with less logic hurdles on your end.

```
$total = 0;
$result = $conn->query("SELECT count(points) as total FROM scores WHERE player_id='$player' ORDER by points ASC");

$row = $result->fetch_array();
if($row['total'] >= 10)
{
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT sum(points) as SumPoints FROM scores WHERE player_id='$player' ORDER by points ASC LIMIT 5");
  $row = $result->fetch_array();
  $total = $row['SumPoints'];
}
```

And you have your value in `$total`